# What is the Volume of a B+ tree

Tags: database, database-design, b-tree

I have a B+ tree like this (please check the pic). It has 18 records now, and I want to figure out what is **how many numbers** that can be added to this tree **without changing its height**.

I think the answer may be 5*5*4=100 but I'm not sure. Thanks for you answer!

[image]

Comment: Explain why it might be that & why you are not sure. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. What parts are you able to do? Where are you stuck? What did your textbook or the documentation say about anything relevant? Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook/manual with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work.

Comment: Look up "B-tree Fanout" on the web.